# Model parametrized API Call in Activity Diagram

Tags: android-activity, model, uml, diagram

I have an an activity diagram with two swimlanes (Client and Server). I want to model a request call from Client to Server.

1. Is it correct to use Signals Notation for Calls between systems? Are there alternatives?
2. The call is parametrized, Client wants to send something which was created before. How to model this?

Thankful for any hint! Here's my example:
[image: link]

Answer (score 3):

My answer has to be improved, but here is a first step.

The norm/spec says: "A SendSignalAction is an InvocationAction that creates a Signal instance and transmits the instance to the object given on its target InputPin. A SendSignalAction must have argument InputPins corresponding, in order, to each of the (owned and inherited) Properties of the Signal being sent, with the same type, ordering and multiplicity as the corresponding attribute.

And a SendSignalAction has an association to a target objet which is an input pin.

So for your question about Request:item I would use input pin, one for the object from which the Signal is created and one to define the Target. (in the schema the target comes from an output pin but a data store may be use). Then after sending the request, the client is waiting the answer. The AcceptEvent is linked to a trigger (not shown on the schema) which a signal, the one created by the server. But you can not link SendRequest of Client to ReceiveRequest of Server because this is not how it runs.

For the server, you can do similar reasoning.

[image]

Comment: I agree I would separate both Server and Client modelling if we really want to express these sending and receiveing signals...

Comment: :) that's tricky and as "usual" the norm/spec is not so clear and lack of examples ...

Comment: aggreed and as usual you can find another way which is more clear for you but once again your solution looks good for me according to what I understood....

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the parametrization of the call I would use InputPin to model the arguments of the Call i.e. the Object sent by the Call as shown below.
[image]

Signal and Call Notations are correct for me but I am not used to have the sending and receive action in the same diagram so will suggest two alternatives.
1) First remove them...
[image]

2) Separate Client and Server Modelling
[image]
[image]

Let me know what you think about that and what seems to be clear for you...
I also recognize the tool you used so please find my project at:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1mx46cb3linop0/Project1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer! Why are the send signals are having input pins, the receive signals output pins. For my understanding, I want to react on a receive signal, therefore I would have expected input pins on the signal receive. But it's also not possible in Modelio. Why?

Comment: In fact, they are not SendSignalAction, they are SendObjectAction (same representation) and the InputPin represent the object sent, Request and ResultSet in your case. Same for OutputPin of ReceiveSignal aka AcceptCallAction, they represent the Object received. 
The signal received is not model thanks to an inputPin but by seeting with kind of signal trigger the reception

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, it should be modeled like this:

[image]

The server runs in an independent loop and starts with waiting for a request. There's a object flow between `Create request` and `Query result set`. This symbolizes data placed in a queue (or what ever is appropriate). The receipt of the result set would be done below in a similar way, I just left that out for brevity.

You can also draw an object for the query set

[image]

instead of the ActionPins.

Comment: @granier Well, no. It's not a control flow, but an object flow. Unfortunately OMG decided to draw object and control flow the same way. You can see it's an object flow since it's going out an action pin (or it's going through an object). The control flow goes just down to `Send request`.

Comment: @kilian it can be discussed but in all examples of the norm object flow show also as control flow, for example fig. 15.14 or 15.18 object flows shows also how actions are linked and executed.

Comment: @granier As I said: OF and CF look the same, but are different. I have never seen the notation from 15.15 to the right anywhere else.